# Accessing a String Enum by index

Tags: swift, enums

I have an enum in C and the index needs to be represented by a String.

How can a Swift enum of String type be used by integer index?

I would like to copy the enum to Swift, set the type to string and define all of the raw values to display text, and then use the C enum value to extract the raw value text for the Swift String enum.

Otherwise I will just create an array of strings.. But the enum would be more usable.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In Swift, enum types do not hold its index info of cases (at least, not provided for programmers).

So:

*How can a Swift enum of String type be used by integer index?*

The answer is "You cannot".

---

You can bind `Int` (or enum cases) and `String` values in many ways other than *just create an array of strings..*

For example, if your bound Strings can be the same as case labels, you can write something like this:

```
enum MyEnum: Int {
    case foo
    case bar
    case baz

    var string: String {
        return String(self)
    }
}

if let value = MyEnum(rawValue: 0) {
    print(value.string) //->foo
}
```

If your Strings need to be a little more complex *to display text*, you can use Swift `Dictionary` to bind enum cases and Strings.

```
enum AnotherEnum: Int {
    case foo
    case bar
    case baz

    static let mapper: [AnotherEnum: String] = [
        .foo: "FooString",
        .bar: "BarString",
        .baz: "BazString"
    ]
    var string: String {
        return AnotherEnum.mapper[self]!
    }
}

if let value = AnotherEnum(rawValue: 1) {
    print(value.string) //->BarString
}
```

A little bit more readable than a simple *array of strings*.

Comment: First solution doesn't work, I have: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(MyEnum)'

Answer (score 53):

**Swift 4.2** introduced `CaseIterable` which does exactly the same thing without the need to declare an `allValues` array. It works like this:

```
enum MyEnum: String, CaseIterable {
    case foo = "fooString"
    case bar = "barString"
    case baz = "bazString"
}
```

and you can access its values by

```
MyEnum.allCases
```

or a value at a specific index by

```
MyEnum.allCases[index]
```

Answer (score 18):

Simple workaround which is also useful if you want to enumerate a string enum.

```
enum MyEnum: String {
    case foo = "fooString"
    case bar = "barString"
    case baz = "bazString"

    static let allValues = [foo, bar, baz] //must maintain second copy of values
}

//enumeration advantage
for value in MyEnum.allValues {
    print(value)
}

//get value by index
let value = MyEnum.allValues[1] 

print(value) //barString
```

Comment: utterly brilliant, thank you. I suspect this will make it into the language itself. Unless of course there is a pre-existing methodology to access the same..

Answer (score 4):

You can add an index as a part of the enum.

```
enum StringEnum: String, CaseIterable {
   case pawn, rook, knight, bishop, king, queen

   var name: String { self.rawValue.uppercased() }
   var index: Int { StringEnum.allCases.firstIndex(of: self) ?? 0 }
}
```

And find enum cases by index with the function:

```
func findEnum(by index: Int) -> StringEnum? {
   StringEnum.allCases.first(where: { $0.index == index })
}
```

Comment: this was a really good solution for me. Thanks.

Comment: Cool suggestion, but the construct `allCases.firstIndex(of:)` might have `O(n)` performance, leading to `n^2` performance if you use it in a loop.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. That solution is good for compact enums. In complex cases you can access enum as an array by index (with CaseIterable).


`func getEnum(by index: Int) -> StringEnum? {
    guard StringEnum.allCases.count > index else { return nil }
    
   return StringEnum.allCases[index]
}